# How can I save a json

Tags: c#, json

I do have this code it fund the good value, but it doesn't save the modification. What can I do ?

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("C:/Files/generated.json"))
{
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Form>>(json);
    foreach (var item in result)
    { 
        if (item.id == FormtoSave.id)
        {
            item.Title = FormtoSave.Title;
            item.body = FormtoSave.body;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to convert the result back to JSON

Comment: yes i want to save the modification i did on the json file

Comment: @user3542017: And what have you tried to save that modification?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to convert your modified object back to a json:

```
string jsonOutput= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

**Edit**:
In order to save the string to a file use this:

```
string path = @"c:\output.json";
File.WriteAllText(path, jsonOutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

After modification in Item title and body you have again serialize object in json and store Json string in file.

```
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("c:\\fileName..json");
        writer.WriteLine("Serialized Json string ");
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the changes back to the file:

```
string resultJson = String.Empty;
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("C:/Files/generated.json"))
{
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Form>>(json);
    foreach (var item in result)
    { 
        if (item.id == FormtoSave.id)
        {
            item.Title = FormtoSave.Title;
            item.body = FormtoSave.body;
        }
    }
    resultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
}
File.WriteAllText("C:/Files/generated.json", resultJson);
```

I did the writing outside the `using` so the file is not still locked by the `StreamReader`.

Or not using a `StreamReader`:

```
string path = "C:/Files/generated.json";
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Form>>(File.ReadAllText(path));
foreach (var item in result)
{ 
    if (item.id == FormtoSave.id)
    {
        item.Title = FormtoSave.Title;
        item.body = FormtoSave.body;
    }
}
File.WriteAllText(path, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Below example will help you

```
List<data> _data = new List<data>();
_data.Add(new data()
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    SSN = 2,
                    Message = "A Message"
                });
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_data.ToArray());

//write string to file
System.IO.File.WriteAllText (@"D:\path.txt", json);
```